# If Condition Based On 2 Columns

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Tring to conditionally execute a query, only when ColumnA = 'New' and ColumnB = 'Left' (in each individual row). I know that str.contains() works when I only have 1 condition, however, I'm getting a ValueError ("ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous..."). Can this approach not be successfully applied, for my given scenario? Alternatively, is there a better approach?

Current code:

```
if df1['ColumnA'].str.contains('New') and df1['ColumnB'].str.contains('Left'):
   do something...
```

Very basic example of the dataframe:

| ColumnA | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| New | Left |
| Used | Right |
| Scrap | Down |
| New | Right |

First row would be the desired row to carry forward (since it meets the criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise `&` on two mask arrays and generate another column.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['New','Used','Scrap','New'], 'B':['Left','Right','Down','Right']})
>>> df
       A      B
0    New   Left
1   Used  Right
2  Scrap   Down
3    New  Right
>>> df['C'] = df['A'].str.contains('New') & df['B'].str.contains('Left')
>>> df
       A      B      C
0    New   Left   True
1   Used  Right  False
2  Scrap   Down  False
3    New  Right  False
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Did not know about the (&). When I try implementing the above, I received the following ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()... thoughts?

Comment: Try putting parenthesis on the conditions like: (condition1) & (condition2)

Comment: parenthesis didn't solve it, it seems that .any() solved it, however, I'm not sure if it performs the same as @Ziming originally wrote

Comment: I've updated the answer. You get a series by `mask1 & mask2`, and cannot use `if` on a series. But you can assign that series to a new column. Then you can loop or select using that new column.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, however it doesn't appear like your code is expressing exactly what you want to do.

```
    df1['ColumnA'].str.contains('New')
```

will return a Series with true and false values corresponding to the indices where the condition is true, not a true or false value for whether the entire column contains 'new'. To accomplish this consider doing something like the following:

```
    'new' in df['ColumnA'].values
```

If you are trying to do it on a row by row basis then you must use the bitwise operator to compare truth values across Series (&).

This will return a boolean like you expected, hopefully this helps (:

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I tried your approach, I received a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str' .... Thoughts?